# changing image color while animating it in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have an image drawn on a canvas. The image for now is doing a simple circular rotation on each frame.
The image scaling is based on the value entered in the text box.

I put the jsfiddle as suggested below

```js
var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;
var image = null;
var slider = null;
var vBox = null;
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var scaleX;
var scaleY;
var center = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
var radius = 50.0;
var angle = 0;
var result = false;
var textActive = false;
var imgArr = null;
var imageData;
var data;

function start() {
  ctx = getCtxReference();
  image = getImageReference();
  result = setOtherReferences();
  imgArr = getStarImages();
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  data = imageData.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    imgArr[i].addEventListener('load', drawBackgroundStar)
  }
  if (image != null && result && imgArr != null) {
    Loop();
  }
}

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "65") {
    changeImgColorToBlue();
  }
}

function getCtxReference() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  return ctx;
}

function getImageReference() {
  image = new Image();
  image.src = "star.png";
  image.addEventListener('load', drawImg);
  return image;
}

function setOtherReferences() {
  slider = document.getElementById("rangeInput");
  vBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
  scaleX = 100;
  scaleY = 100;
  center.x = canvas.width / 3;
  center.y = canvas.height / 3;
  return true;
}

function getStarImages() {
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "star.png";
    arr.push(img);
  }
  return arr;
}

function drawImg() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, scaleX, scaleY);
  return true;
}

function drawBackgroundStar() {
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(imgArr[i], getRandomArbitrary(0, canvas.width), getRandomArbitrary(0, canvas.height), getRandomArbitrary(5, 15), getRandomArbitrary(5, 15));
  }
}

function Loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  window.setTimeout(Loop, 100);
  angle += Math.PI * 0.05;
  x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(angle);
  vBox.value = slider.value;
  updateStarScale();
  drawImg();
  //drawBackgroundStar();
}

function updateStarScale() {
  if (vBox.value > 0) {
    scaleX += vBox.value / 10;
    scaleY += vBox.value / 10;
    changeImgColorToBlue();
  } else if (vBox.value < 0) {
    scaleX -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
    scaleY -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
    changeImgColorToRed();
  }

  if (scaleX > 600 || scaleY > 600) {
    scaleX = 600;
    scaleY = 600;
  } else if (scaleX < 50 || scaleY < 50) {
    scaleX = 50;
    scaleY = 50;
  }
}

function changeImgColorToBlue() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    data[i] = 0; // red
    data[i + 1] = 0; // green
    data[i + 2] = 255; // blue
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function changeImgColorToRed() {

}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("stars.png");
  }
  #container {
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  #textBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 5px;
  }
  #slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 200px;
  }
</style>

<body onload="start()">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="textBox">
      Velocity:
      <input type="text" id="textbox" value="0">
    </div>
    <div id="slider">
      Slider:
      <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
        <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="-100" max="100" step="3" value="">
        <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

So in my Loop(), I am updating the position of my image. In the updateStarScale() I am scaling the image size based on the value given in the text box by the user. All of this works fine. My only concern is the changeImgColorToBlue() which does nothing to the image color. I want the image color to be changed to blue but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

---

**

> UPDATE 1.0:

**

After suggestions from the last post, I changed the code to below. There are two yellow stars on the screen now and they scale up based on the sliders but alongside scaling I want their colors to change ie when they are scaled up they turn blue and when they are scaled down they turn red but the colors don't change.

```js
//Create the images(Using a canvas for CORS issues)
function createStars() {
  var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  imgCanvas.height = "500";
  imgCanvas.width = "500";
  var imgCtx = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
  imgCtx.fillStyle = 'black';
  imgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
  imgCtx.fillStyle = '#FF0';
  for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 250; i++) {
    imgCtx.fillRect(Math.random() * 500, Math.random() * 500, 1, 1)
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imgCanvas.toDataURL() + ')';
}
createStars();

var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;
var image = null;
var slider = null;
var vBox = null;
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var scaleX;
var scaleY;
var center = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
var radius = 50.0;
var angle = 0;
var result = false;
var imageData;
var data;
var backgroundImg = null;


function start() {
  ctx = getCtxReference();
  result = setOtherReferences();
  image = getStarImages();

  if (image != null)
    image.addEventListener('load', Loop);
}

function getCtxReference() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  return ctx;
}


function setOtherReferences() {
  slider = document.getElementById("rangeInput");
  vBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
  scaleX = 150;
  scaleY = 150;
  center.x = canvas.width / 3;
  center.y = canvas.height / 3;
  return true;
}

function getStarImages() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = createStar();
  return img;
}


function createStar() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0';
  ctx.fillRect(Math.random() * 45, Math.random() * 45, scaleX, scaleY);
  return canvas.toDataURL();
}

function drawImg() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, scaleX, scaleY);
}


function Loop() {
  window.setTimeout(Loop, 100);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  angle += Math.PI * 0.05;
  x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(angle);
  vBox.value = slider.value;
  updateStarScale();
  drawImg();
}

function updateStarScale() {
  if (vBox.value > 0) {
    scaleX += vBox.value / 10;
    scaleY += vBox.value / 10;
    changeImgColorToBlue();
  } else if (vBox.value < 0) {
    scaleX -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
    scaleY -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
    changeImgColorToRed();
  }

  if (scaleX > 600 || scaleY > 600) {
    scaleX = 600;
    scaleY = 600;
  } else if (scaleX < 50 || scaleY < 50) {
    scaleX = 50;
    scaleY = 50;
  }
}

function changeImgColorToBlue() {
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  data = imageData.data;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    //is our data black?
    if (data[i] > 0 || data[i + 1] > 0 || data[i + 2] > 0) {
      data[i] = 0; // red
      data[i + 1] = 0; // green
      data[i + 2] = 255; // blue
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function changeImgColorToRed() {
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  data = imageData.data;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    if (data[i] > 0 || data[i + 1] > 0 || data[i + 2] > 0) {
      data[i] = 255; // red
      data[i + 1] = 0; // green
      data[i + 2] = 0; // blue
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

start();
```

Comment: how about you set up a jsfiddle to help us see what you are doing?

Comment: I did as you suggested. Apologies if its not what you meant as I am new to posting JavaScript questions here.

Comment: Your `changeImgColorToBlue` has a funny for loop. The first round changes `data[0], data[1], data[2]` then the next round changes `data[4], data[5], data[6]`. You probably just want to set the RGB value once. Also `ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)` isn't doing anything.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to manipulate pixel data. I just copy pasted the code snippet from internet just to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

Ok, so if you only need to draw those moving stars, you can simplify a lot your code, especially about the changing color :
As each star is only a colored rectangle, you only have to store a `color` value (i.e hex) and update it when you want to the desired color. No bitmap calculation needed.
However, as your code is right now, if you try to create new stars, they will all follow the same path and scale update.
I think that you will have to rethink the way you update the position.

Here is an update, with simplification of the code and example showing the issue

```js
function createStars() {
  var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  imgCanvas.height = "500";
  imgCanvas.width = "500";
  var imgCtx = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
  imgCtx.fillStyle = 'black';
  imgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
  imgCtx.fillStyle = '#FF0';
  for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 250; i++) {
    imgCtx.fillRect(Math.random() * 500, Math.random() * 500, 1, 1)
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imgCanvas.toDataURL() + ')';
}
createStars();

var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;
var slider = null;
var vBox = null;
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var center = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
var radius = 50.0;
var angle = 0;
var result = false;
var color = "FF0"; // set the color as a global variable, avoiding a function to set it
var stars = []; // set an array that will contain all our moving stars

function start() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  result = setOtherReferences();
  // append new stars to our array
  stars.push(createStar());
  stars.push(createStar());
  stars.push(createStar());
  // start the Loop()
  Loop();
}

function setOtherReferences() {
  slider = document.getElementById("rangeInput");
  vBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
  center.x = canvas.width / 3;
  center.y = canvas.height / 3;
  return true;
}


function createStar() {
  // set moving stars as object, with their own x,y,width and height properties.
  var star = {
    xStart: Math.random() * 150,  // used in order to avoid the exact 
    yStart: Math.random() * 150, // same position of your stars
    x: this.xStart,
    y: this.yStart,
    w: 50,
    h: 50
  }
  return star;
}

function drawImg() {
  // set the moving stars color to the actual growing/shrinking state
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  // for each of our moving stars, draw a rect
  for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(stars[i].x, stars[i].y, stars[i].w, stars[i].h);
  }
}


function Loop() {
  window.setTimeout(Loop, 100);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  angle += Math.PI * 0.05;
  /* 
     Here is the main issue 
     as each of our stars x/y pos are updated with the same function,
     they will follow each others.
     I added the xStart property so they're not 
     exactly at the same position for you beeing able to see it.
  */
  for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i].x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(angle) + stars[i].xStart;
    stars[i].y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(angle) + stars[i].yStart;
  }
  vBox.value = slider.value;
  updateStarScale();
  drawImg();
}

function updateStarScale() {
  //same as above, each of our stars will have the same scale update
  for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    if (vBox.value > 0) {
      stars[i].w += vBox.value / 10;
      stars[i].h += vBox.value / 10;
      color = "#00F";
    } else if (vBox.value < 0) {
      stars[i].w -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
      stars[i].h -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
      color = "#F00";
    }

    if (stars[i].w > 600 || stars[i].h > 600) {
      stars[i].w = 600;
      stars[i].h = 600;
    } else if (stars[i].w < 5 || stars[i].h < 5) {
      stars[i].w = 5;
      stars[i].h = 5;
    }
  }
}

// Only call it if you haven't already done (i.e in a load event)
start();
```

```css
body {
   text-align: center;
   background-image: url("stars.png");
 }
 #container {
   position: fixed;
   color: red;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
 }
 #textBox {
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   left: 5px;
 }
 #slider {
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   left: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
<div id="container">
  <div id="textBox">
    Velocity:
    <input type="text" id="textbox" value="0">
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    Slider:
    <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
      <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="-100" max="100" step="3" value="0">
      <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Original answer

First, You will need to update your `imageData` each time you call `changeImgColorToBlue`.
Secondly, in order to not change all your pixels into blue, you will have to check if each pixel is in some range of color.
Assuming your star.png does look like a black background with colored dots over it, you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    if( data[i]>0 || data[i+1]>0 || data[i+2]>0 ){
    //is our pixel black?
    data[i] = 0;// red
    data[i + 1] = 0; // green
    data[i + 2] = 255; // blue
    }
}
```

Of course, you can change those conditions to match for the actual color of your dots with more precision by using e.g if your dots are yellow
 `if( data[i]>=200 && data[i+1]>=200 && data[i+2]<100 )`

Also, I did some changes in your code as you had redundant calls to some functions.

```js
//Create the images(Using a canvas for CORS issues)
function createStars(){
var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
imgCanvas.height="500";
imgCanvas.width="500";
var imgCtx = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
imgCtx.fillStyle= 'black';
imgCtx.fillRect(0,0,500,500)
imgCtx.fillStyle= '#FF0';
for(i=0; i<Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+250; i++){
  imgCtx.fillRect(Math.random()*500, Math.random()*500, 1,1)
  }
document.body.style.backgroundImage='url('+imgCanvas.toDataURL()+')';
}
createStars();
function createStar(){
var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
imgCanvas.height="50";
imgCanvas.width="50";
var imgCtx = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
imgCtx.fillStyle= '#FF0';
imgCtx.fillRect(Math.random()*45,Math.random()*45, 5,5);
return imgCanvas.toDataURL();
}

var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;
var image = null;
var slider = null;
var vBox = null;
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var scaleX;
var scaleY;
var center = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
var radius = 50.0;
var angle = 0;
var result = false;
var textActive = false;
var imgArr = null;
var imageData;
var data;
var backgroundImg = null;


function start() {
  ctx = getCtxReference();
  result = setOtherReferences();
  image = getStarImages();
  if (image != null && result && imgArr != null) {
    Loop();
  }
}

function getCtxReference() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  return ctx;
}


function setOtherReferences() {
  slider = document.getElementById("rangeInput");
  vBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
  scaleX = 100;
  scaleY = 100;
  center.x = canvas.width / 3;
  center.y = canvas.height / 3;
  return true;
}

function drawImg() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, scaleX, scaleY);
  return true;
}


function Loop() {
  window.setTimeout(Loop, 100);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0,0);
  angle += Math.PI * 0.05;
  x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(angle);
  vBox.value = slider.value;
  updateStarScale();
  drawImg();
}

function getStarImages() {
  //as they're all the same image, you don't need to make an array of them, simply make a loop below
  var img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', drawBackgroundStar)
  img.src = createStar();
  return img;
}

function drawBackgroundStar() {
  for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, getRandomArbitrary(0, canvas.width), getRandomArbitrary(0, canvas.height), getRandomArbitrary(5, 15), getRandomArbitrary(5, 15));
  }
    backgroundImg = new Image();
    backgroundImg.addEventListener('load', Loop);
    backgroundImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();

}

function updateStarScale() {
  if (vBox.value > 0) {
    scaleX += vBox.value / 10;
    scaleY += vBox.value / 10;
   changeImgColorToBlue();
  } else if (vBox.value < 0) {
    scaleX -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
    scaleY -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
    changeImgColorToRed();
  }

  if (scaleX > 600 || scaleY > 600) {
    scaleX = 600;
    scaleY = 600;
  } else if (scaleX < 50 || scaleY < 50) {
    scaleX = 50;
    scaleY = 50;
  }
}

function changeImgColorToBlue() {
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  data = imageData.data;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    //is our data black?
    if(data[i]>0||data[i+1]>0||data[i+2]>0){
    data[i] = 0;// red
    data[i + 1] = 0; // green
    data[i + 2] = 255; // blue
 }
    }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function changeImgColorToRed() {
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  data = imageData.data;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    if(data[i]>0||data[i+1]>0||data[i+2]>0){
    data[i] = 255;// red
    data[i + 1] = 0; // green
    data[i + 2] = 0; // blue
 }
    }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

start();
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #container {
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  #textBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 5px;
  }
  #slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="textBox">
      Velocity:
      <input type="text" id="textbox" value="0">
    </div>
    <div id="slider">
      Slider:
      <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
        <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="-100" max="100" step="3" value="">
        <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you wrote it, the `changeImgColorToBlue` functions are only changing the background stars of your canvas. I'm not sure it is what you want to achieve so here is a way to only change this one dot :

```js
function createStars(){
var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
imgCanvas.height="500";
imgCanvas.width="500";
var imgCtx = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
imgCtx.fillStyle= 'black';
imgCtx.fillRect(0,0,500,500)
imgCtx.fillStyle= '#FF0';
for(i=0; i<Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+250; i++){
  imgCtx.fillRect(Math.random()*500, Math.random()*500, 1,1)
  }
document.body.style.backgroundImage='url('+imgCanvas.toDataURL()+')';
}
createStars();
function createStar(){
var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
imgCanvas.height="50";
imgCanvas.width="50";
var imgCtx = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
imgCtx.fillStyle= '#FF0';
imgCtx.fillRect(Math.random()*45,Math.random()*45, 5,5);
return imgCanvas.toDataURL();
}

var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;
var starCanvas = null;
var starCtx = null;
var image = null;
var slider = null;
var vBox = null;
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var scaleX;
var scaleY;
var center = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
var radius = 50.0;
var angle = 0;
var result = false;
var textActive = false;
var imgArr = null;
var imageData;
var data;
var backgroundImg = null;


function start() {
  ctx = getCtxReference();
  starCtx = getStarReference();
  result = setOtherReferences();
  image = getStarImages();
  if (image != null && result && imgArr != null && backgroundImg != null) {
    Loop();
  }
}

function getCtxReference() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  return canvas.getContext('2d');
}
function getStarReference() {
  starCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  starCanvas.height = 50;
  starCanvas.width = 50;
  starCanvas.id=('star');
  document.body.appendChild(starCanvas);
  return starCanvas.getContext('2d');
  
}

function setOtherReferences() {
  slider = document.getElementById("rangeInput");
  vBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
  scaleX = 100;
  scaleY = 100;
  center.x = canvas.width / 3;
  center.y = canvas.height / 3;
  return true;
}

function drawImg() {
  ctx.drawImage(starCanvas, x, y, scaleX, scaleY);
  return true;
}


function Loop() {
  window.setTimeout(Loop, 100);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0,0);
  angle += Math.PI * 0.05;
  x = center.x + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(angle);
  vBox.value = slider.value;
  updateStarScale();
  drawImg();
}

function getStarImages() {
  //as they're all the same image, you don't need to make an array of them, simply make a loop below
  var img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', drawBackgroundStar)
  img.src = createStar();
  return img;
}

function drawBackgroundStar() {
  for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, getRandomArbitrary(0, canvas.width), getRandomArbitrary(0, canvas.height), getRandomArbitrary(5, 15), getRandomArbitrary(5, 15));
  }
   backgroundImg = new Image();
   backgroundImg.addEventListener('load', Loop);
   backgroundImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();
   
   starCtx.drawImage(image, 0,0,50,50)
}

function updateStarScale() {
  if (vBox.value > 0) {
    scaleX += vBox.value / 10;
    scaleY += vBox.value / 10;
   changeImgColorToBlue();
  } else if (vBox.value < 0) {
    scaleX -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
    scaleY -= Math.abs(vBox.value / 10);
    changeImgColorToRed();
  }

  if (scaleX > 600 || scaleY > 600) {
    scaleX = 600;
    scaleY = 600;
  } else if (scaleX < 50 || scaleY < 50) {
    scaleX = 50;
    scaleY = 50;
  }
}

function changeImgColorToBlue() {
  imageData = starCtx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
  data = imageData.data;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    //is our data black?
    if(data[i]>0||data[i+1]>0||data[i+2]>0){
    data[i] = 0;// red
    data[i + 1] = 0; // green
    data[i + 2] = 255; // blue
 }
    }
  starCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function changeImgColorToRed() {
  imageData = starCtx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
  data = imageData.data;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    if(data[i]>0||data[i+1]>0||data[i+2]>0){
    data[i] = 255;// red
    data[i + 1] = 0; // green
    data[i + 2] = 0; // blue
 }
    }
  starCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

start();
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #container {
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  #textBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 5px;
  }
  #slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="textBox">
      Velocity:
      <input type="text" id="textbox" value="0">
    </div>
    <div id="slider">
      Slider:
      <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
        <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="-100" max="100" step="3" value="">
        <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the brush up in my code. That really helped a lot!

Comment: Hey I changed the code a bit to fit my goals. I just need one star, the "yellow star" from your code that rotates on the screen, scales up and down based on the slider and changes the color accordingly. I change the code and got it to a point where there is are just two yellow stars but the color does not change for those stars. Can you please take a look into it. I have updated my original post